# Problem with CSS using laravel Backpack loading some style which I don't know where come from

Tags: css

i'm moving a project to Laravel backpack. I copied the front views from the project. But something is messing up my theme. The theme does not look the same if I use a backpack. The styles for a particular button do not look the same even though the HTML and CSS are identical in both cases.

This is how I see the button in packpack project  front
[image]

this is how it should look
[image]

This is the syle for that button:

```
.selectorhotelfeat .owl-prev,.selectorhotelfeat .owl-next    {
height: 80px;
/*width: 65px;*/
/*background: #fff;*/
text-align: center;
line-height: 62px;
font-size: 60px;
color: #7e7e7e;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
z-index: 3;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 300ms linear 0s;
```

}

In the computed styles I can see an attribute which is not present in the original project.

appearance: button

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't look like a default Backpack component. Are you seeing this in your front-end (visitor-facing part of the project) or in your back-end (admin panel)?

Comment: This is the front-end. Something seems to override certain styles. But I can't find how or where

Answer (score 0):

It may be `Laravel Backpack` override your Custom CSS :

But if you need to style button to look like the second `image` do some tricks as example :

1. Try `border:none;` to remove the border that around button
2. Try `text-align: center;` to center arrow icon or using `<center></center>` Tag
3. Try `margin-left:;` Or `margin-right:;` to postion your button

This All what I know to answer this question